# Where did google app engine plugin output the client library to?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Using the Eclipse Google App Engine tool inside the Eclipse IDE I right-clicked on my java project and selected 'Google->Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library' a progress window appears and closes when done. 
Where did google app engine plugin output the client library to?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the popup window and the client library is placed in the 'endpoints-libs' folder, which is viewable in the Package Explorer in Eclipse.